# Set curve to selected vertices

Tags: modeling

So below I have a selected set of vertices. I want to have a curve with the exact shape of these vertices. How could I take a curve and line it up to the exact shape of the vertices I have selected?

[image]

Comment: Why can't you just Alt-C and convert the mesh to a curve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select said vertex in *Edit Mode*
2. Duplicate it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
3. Separate them from the main shape with <kbd>P</kbd> > *Selection*
4. Exit *Edit Mode*, select the newly created "wire mesh" and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > *Curve from Mesh*

Comment: So I have made it into a curve but the array isn't following it properly...https://gyazo.com/36e3a2fa16e49af7dfb769d0d2315f42. how do I go about making it follow the curve.

Comment: @FrosticWolf - please ask a new question to address that.  If this answers this particular question, please mark it as "Accepted".